# How to access data objects from outside of infinitely running asyncio event loop?

Tags: python, multithreading, async-await, python-asyncio

Currently working with a server simulator that is initialized via a call to `asyncio.run().`
After calling `await` on a number of coroutines, it is designed to run as an infinite loop that serves continuously.

One of the coroutines that inits the server creates a `ModbusTcpServer` object that I need to access from the top level (the file that initially makes the call to `asyncio.run()`). How can I access this data if the coroutines are designed to run infinitely and never return? I'd ultimately like to get the data so I can change values in a GUI such as PyQT5. Here is sample of my code:

```py
def start_server():
    cmd_args = get_commandline()
    run_args = setup_simulator(cmd_args)
    asyncio.run(run_server_simulator(run_args), debug=True)

######
async def run_server_simulator(args):
    await StartAsyncTcpServer(
        context=args.context,
        address=("", args.port),
        framer=args.framer,
        allow_reuse_address=True,
    )
```

The `StartAsyncTcpServer()` function creates the object that I want to modify and then awaits a coroutine that creates a task that runs forever.

I've tried manually creating an event loop using
`asyncio.new_event_loop()`
yet this still doesn't provide me access to the data from within the coroutines, only the loop itself. Not only that, but doing this gives me an error that my first coroutine was never awaited.

I've also attempted initializing the first of my coroutines via `asyncio.create_task()`, and calling `await` on the task object but awaiting them never provides return values because the coroutines never finish.

Comment: AFAIK PyQt does not support asyncio, you can use [qtrio](https://qtrio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

Comment: You say that the function `StartAsyncTcpServer` creates the object that you want to modify, but you don't say that it allows access to that object or to the data it handles.  That doesn't sound useful.  Does the function return the object?  Does the function support callbacks, or put its data on a queue, or something like that?  Without something like that there is no solution, except to modify the function.  This sort of problem has nothing to do with asyncio - if any kind of routine (sync or async) creates an object but doesn't allow access, you've got exactly the same situation.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

I ultimately settled on the simple solution of passing my object into the coroutine such that its fields get set in another module prior to the infinitely running loop's initialization.

```
 loop.create_task(server_py.run_server_simulator(ctrl))
```

where `ctrl` is my object